# adding multiple tds into an extra array to add to a tr element node

Tags: javascript

i have a var list with some values inside.
Those values are each created as a textnode by what was insert in the table input fields like this:

```
<td><input id="a" type="text" cam-variable-name="a" /></td>
<td><input id="b" type="text" cam-variable-name="b" /</td>
<td><input id="c" type="text" cam-variable-name="c" /></td>

var a= document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("a").value);
var b= document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("b").value);
var c= document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("c").value);
var list[a,b,c]
```

now i have the td objects iterated

```
for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){var node_td = document.createElement('td');
node_td.id=i;
node_td.appendChild(list[i]);
```

I have the problem, that each td element should be somehow pushed in a new array, so I can iterate over that array, like listNode[].
I cant get the element by id, since it's not in the document yet, but I have to put all the tds in a tr node so it wont just give me one field "c" in my table.. anyone know how i can obtain that`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var ids = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    trElement = ids
        .map(function( id ) {
            return document.querySelector('#' + id);
        })
        .reduce(function( tr, node ) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.id = node.value;
            tr.appendChild(td);
            return tr;
        }, document.createElement('tr'));
```

And them append the trElement to your table.

Comment: There's also a handy-dandy type of DOM node that specifically exists to "put objects in."  When you add this node to the DOM, what actually happens instead is that *its contents* are added at that position, instead: the node itself is not. *(Pardon me for momentarily forgetting what it is called, and for being too lazy right now to go look it up.)*

Comment: `document.createDocumentFragment()` The difference being that you can use querySelector and getElementByX and such on a real node but not on a fragment.

Comment: *Bingo!* That's the one. One of the very-nicest ideas that the designers of DOM ever came up with. You coin a fragment-object, add things to it, and then insert it somewhere. DOM responds by inserting *what the fragment contains* at that point, but not the fragment itself. "Unbelievably handy."

Comment: but the tr element doesn't need an id. just the td element. And i don't  quite get why I should map the _a b c_ to the _tr_ element.. And how are _a b c_ added to the _td_ element in this way? Furthermore: _a b c_ is just an example, I actually have 10 values..

Comment: Just replacing redundant code. You basically loop through the array containing all of the id's of input elements you want to make a td element for. The first loop (map) grabs all these elements and returns then in a new array, and then the reduce loop creates a td node and appends it to the tr element. The tr doesn't get an id from these loops.

Comment: thank you :) but I have one more issue. When I use _td.appendChild(list[i]);_it just adds all items just to the last td. how can i fix that?

Comment: You have to append the td node somewhere before creating the next node. There is no block scope in javascript so every time you loop `var node_td = document.createElement('td');`, you overwrite the previous node_td. So append it before overwriting it.

Comment: I'm pretty new to javascript so.. -i am sorry for the noob question, but how would I actually acomplish that?

Comment: Yor're creating td nodes, these have to be appended to a tr element and the tr element ahs to be appended to a table element. So create a tr element like you created td elements and then append to it. I'm assuming you want to append this new row (containing the cells, which each contain a text node with the value of an input) to some table in your page.

Comment: `node_tr = list2
        .reduce(function( node ) {    
   
   for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
   
   var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.id = i;
   
  td.appendChild(list[i]);
   
            node_tr.appendChild(td);
            return node_tr;}
        }, document.createElement('tr'));`
thats what i have atm but it doesnt quite work... i dont get where i can break the scope...or how

Comment: Just forget about the reduce and just use the normal loop like before. Inside your own for-loop add `node_tr.appendChild(node_td);` Be sure to create the node_tr element Outside the loop, since you want One tr element to add all the td's to. Or create an array and use `aryName.push(node_td);` as you suggested youself.